# How to create MySQL table with specific no. of rows?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to create a MySQL table using PHP. It should have an exact 12 rows and 4 columns. The first column will be `id`.

I am using this code to create table:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `$table` (
      id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      name VARCHAR(30),
      pin INT(11),
      country VARCHAR(30)
    )";

try {
    $db->exec($sql);
    echo 'Table created!';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The above code is creating table successfully but what I want is that it should create 12 rows and the `id` column to be filled till 12. The remaining column should be empty.

Comment: You have to INSERT twelve rows into the table. You can not create it with twelve rows in it.

Comment: I don't think it could be done with MySql. Programmatically you could check for every Insert if the table has more than 12 rows and do nothing if it does. Also you could make a trigger in MySql (don't sure if MySql has triggers psql does) so the trigger count rows before every insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only creates empty table with 4 columns. Than you need to `INSERT` some data to that table:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO {$table} (name, pin, country) VALUES ';
$inserts = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
    $inserts[] = "('', 0, '')"; // Or any other values. No ID, because it's auto-incremented
}

$db->exec($sql.implode(', ', $inserts));
```

Comment: It would be better to use a prepared statement and execute it multiple times.

Comment: @Daniels118 I don't think so, because you add no variables, only empty entries. And why to execute insert multiple times if you can do it only once?

Comment: Because concatenating strings could be heavy for higher number of inserts, and also the sql parser have to interpret multiple times the same query, which is an useless overhead. I have upvoted your solution because this is not the case, my comment was for a more general case.

Answer (score 0):

plese try this coding

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `$table` (
  id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30),
  pin INT(11),
  country VARCHAR(30)
)";
mysql_query($sql);

    for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++) {
   $insert = "INSERT INTO `$table` (id,name,pin,country) VALUES ($i,'','','') ";
   mysql_query($insert);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, also query can be optimized to insert only once

Comment: why? Is there any spcific reason ?

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated, inserting in every iteration is very slow.

Comment: @aruncbe83 Insted of using `mysql_*`, you should use `mysqli` or `PDO`